# RxJs polling, error handling, retryWhen & retryCount resetting

Tags: angular, rxjs, polling

I'm trying to implement a polling strategy that works like the following:

- Request data from server every X seconds
- if request fails, display error message: "Error receiving data, retry attempt N°"...
  And retry every X seconds for a maximum of Y times
- if retry count > Y then display error message "Error receiving data, please try again later"

The code so far is like the following:

```
  polling$ = combineLatest([timer(0, 1000), this._filters]).pipe(
exhaustMap((_) =>
  this.noteDataService.getAll().pipe(
    retryWhen((error$) =>
      error$.pipe(
        map((err, i) => ({ err, i })),
        tap(({ i }) =>
          console.log(`Error receiving data, retry attempt ${i + 1}`)
        ),
        // retry every X seconds for a maximum of Y times
        take(5),
        delay(1000),
        tap({
          complete: () =>
            console.log("Error receiving data, please try again later"),
        })
      )
    )
  )
)
```

);

The problem is that after X attempts it doesn't stop and re-attempts again for X times...etc. i guess i has to do with the first timer in the combineLatest operator but i don't see a solution, i tried plugging the "first" operator but then the polling doesn't re-attempt X times after the first failure.

Comment: I use combineLatest to filter the data, _filters.next() can be called to get the data filtered with query params

Answer (score 0):

It's totally fine to use a local variable to keep the retry count. Also, you would like to use `concat` here, to ensure that emitting is not happening in parallel:

```js
  startPolling(interval = 1000, retry = 10): Observable<Response> {
    let retryCount = 0;

    // pull the data every "interval" seconds
    return timer(0, interval).pipe(
      switchMap((_) => this.requestData()),
      tap((res) => {
        if (!res.ok) {
          // if response is failed, throw error, so "retryWhen" will be triggered
          throw res;
        } else {
          // if response is success, reset retryCount
          retryCount = 0;
        }
      }),
      retryWhen((res) => {
        return res.pipe(
          // use "concatMap" to ensure that data emitting will be happening in order
          concatMap((data) => {
            // if we exceed retry count, then just interrupt "retryWhen" loop
            if (retryCount >= retry) {
              console.log('Error receiving data, please try again later');
              return throwError(EMPTY);
            }

            // increment retry count and run next delay next retry
            retryCount += 1;
            console.log(`Error receiving data. Retry number ${retryCount}`);
            return of(data).pipe(delay(interval));
          }),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how I would do this. For the most part, you can use RxJS operators to manage state for you, no need to create your own local variables.

```ts
const requestData = () => timer(2000).pipe(
  tap(_ => {throw "This is an error";})
);

// Request data from server every X seconds
const requestInterval = 1000;
interval(requestInterval).pipe(
  exhaustMap(_ => requestData().pipe(
    retryWhen(error$ => error$.pipe(
      map((err,i) => ({err,i})),
      tap(({i}) => console.log(`Error receiving data, retry attempt ${i + 1}`)),
      // retry every X seconds for a maximum of Y times
      take(5),
      delay(requestInterval),
      tap({
        complete: () => console.log("Error receiving data, please try again later")
      })
    ))
  ))
).subscribe();
```

---

#### Update:

If you want your polling interval to error out after you get too many consecutive errors, instead of completing your `retryWhen` observable, you can emit an error.

```ts
const requestData = () => timer(2000).pipe(
  tap(_ => {throw "This is an error";})
);

// Request data from server every X seconds
const requestInterval = 1000;
interval(requestInterval).pipe(
  exhaustMap(_ => requestData().pipe(
    retryWhen(error$ => error$.pipe(
      map((err,i) => ({err,i})),
      tap(({i}) => console.log(`Error receiving data, retry attempt ${i + 1}`)),
      // retry every X seconds for a maximum of Y times
      take(5),
      delay(requestInterval),
      concatWith(throwError(() => "Error receiving data, please try again later"))
    ))
  ))
).subscribe({error: e => console.log("Printing the error: ", e)});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, i still have a problem thou when i use your method after X attempts it doesn't stop and retries for another X attempts...etc. I updated tho code in the original post

Comment: I thought that's what you were after... Even so, that's an easy fix. Just change the source of the `retryWhen` from the `requestData` to the `interval`.

Comment: @user7616817 - I've included an update to my answer